# Memory usage when "cutting" a string variable and assigning the new part to the same variable name

Tags: python, string, memory, indexing

Basic python question here:
say I have a string variable

```
x='sdfghjk'
```

and I need to use just some of the string's characters, and assign them to the same name, e.g.

```
x=x[x.index('g'):]
```

Does the new `x` come "instead" of the old one in terms of memory, or am I creating duplicates and using extra memory for no reason?

Comment: Strings in particular are tricky to talk about since the interpreter does optimization in a lot of cases to specifically try to maximize efficiencies, but you are creating a new string each time you slice, pretty much.  That said, unless you have another reference to the original string somewhere, it will be released and cleaned up by the gc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable points to a different memory. As you see,

```
>>> x='gewfsafg'
>>> id(x)
140290029218384
>>> x=x[x.index('f'):]
>>> x
'fsafg'
>>> id(x)
140290029218288
```

The id of x is changed and the old memory is cleaned

Comment: Thank u Awsin. I was not aware of the id function.

Answer (score 4):

> Does the new x come "instead" of the old one in terms of memory, or am I creating duplicates, and using extra memory for no reason.

Python strings are immutable, so you're creating a duplicate, which will require more memory. If you were instead to do...

```
>>> x = 'sdfghjk'
>>> x = buffer(x, x.index('g'))
>>> print x
ghjk
```

...you'll get a similar result, but the `x` variable now refers to the same block of memory the original string was allocated in, which may be preferable if you're dealing with a massive string.

Or if you want a mutable string, try a [`bytearray`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray).